Is there a method to display just a single cell value from a Google sheet on a Google site?
On the bottom line I want to read/display a value (and nothing else) from a Google sheet on a Google site. This is with a common Google account.
The preparations I have made is that I have a sheet, which is completely open for anyone. The sheet is published on the web (file/share) and the script for the sheet is:
function doGet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1qegJvvMUTR8B_CYNB9bnG2Ht20RPjXQ8uiK0pOiI4mU').getActiveSheet();
  var value = sheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(value);
}

The script is deployed as a web app, with the following configurations:

The web address is: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxHtjx31MHklzaRBXMIBUc21XWxrf4NmIQLeQ0KE1DgPg2-_3ub56Joyh0ZEbBgcB9i/exec - Which works fine with a browser.
The problem is that when I try to embed the URL in a Google Site I get a no access message.
Both files (sheet and site) can be seen in this drive folder: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1-0RR2J5WOehQ4axaBdyJsTs7djPFTY7r
I am open to other ways to display a the cell value.

When the script is tested, it seems that the error You need access shows up after being embedded in Google Sites, regardless if the account being used is a Google Workspace or a regular Google account.
Upon reviewing the code, the cause of the error is
return ContentService.createTextOutput(value);


The documentation of createTextOutput(content) doesn't state that it requires additional access, so I recommend that you submit a bug report to let Google know about the unusual behavior that's going on.

In the mean time, you may change that to:
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<p>" + value + "</p>");

After being embedded, it should give something like this:

To increase the font size of what'll show up in Google Sites, you may change that to:
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<p style='font-size: 25px'>" + value + "</p>");


REFERENCE

createHtmlOutput(html)

